# Why doesn't my rust project output anything?

Tags: rust

my point of this program is to see if certain processes are running. My code checks with no problem, but it doesn't output anything.
It creates the file, but that's it. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. I've already spent 3 weeks on the project I'm adding this code to, and it is really frustrating af.

Code:

```
use sysinfo::{ProcessExt, System, SystemExt};
use std::fs::{OpenOptions, write};
use std::io::Error;

fn get_process(pid: &str) -> Result<(), Error>
{
    let _log = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .open("process_list.txt")?;
    
    let p = System::new_all();
    for mut _proc in p.processes_by_exact_name(pid)
    {
        let is_up = _proc.name();
        if is_up == "Opera"
        {
            write("process_list.txt", b"Opera is up")?;
        
        //}else if is_up == "Google Chrome"{
            //println!("chrome is running");
        
        //}else if is_up == "Firefox" {
            //println!("firefox is running");
        
        }else{
            write("process_list.txt", b"NOTHING IS RUNNING!!!")?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main()
{    
    loop {
        
        get_process("Opera").ok();
    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a function by the name `processes_by_exact_name` in [the docs](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.11.5/sysinfo/trait.SystemExt.html?search=processes_by_exact_name). Where is that function coming from?

Comment: because presumably there is no process called 'Opera', your code says 'enumerate all process called Opera'

Comment: @SilvioMayolo crate sysinfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for errors instead of ignoring them. If you replace `get_process("Opera").ok();` with `get_process("Opera").unwrap();`, you should see an error message complaining that your program couldn't open file `process_list.txt` for writing.

This is because you try to open the file *twice*: the first time in `let _log = …` then again when calling `write("process_list.txt", …)`. But the second time fails because the file is still open from the first time.

You should either get rid of the `_log` variable since you don't use it, or use `_log.write (…)?;` to write to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response and your time. When I replaced ``ok()`` with ``unwrap()`` it didn't give me an error either, but I still changed the way I was writing to the file, and with no errors, it is still not outputting to the file. I'm using vs code to work with windows(Idk if this info will help or not, so just in case).

Comment: Then quite probably `processes_by_exact_name` is returning an empty list, so you never call `write`. Note that it is unlikely that Opera will have exactly `"Opera"` as its process name: on Windows it would probably be `"Opera.exe"` and on Linux `"opera"` (lower-case `o`) + possibly a path. Can you try listing all process names with [`processes`](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/0.23.5/sysinfo/trait.SystemExt.html#tymethod.processes) and check the real name used by Opera?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, for how to write t a file properly, and using ```unwrap()```, and you was right that the process was actually ```opera.exe```, now everything works.